# Returns new columns for selected values

Tags: sql, aggregation

How can I write a query that fixes the number of Guava and Berry being the same number as no_of_fruits? Guava and Berry have their own numbers.

PS. The fruits_opt column have two values (Guava & Berry)

```
SELECT 
DATETRUNC(date_ts,'dd') AS day,
COUNT(sold_fruits) AS no_of_fruits_sold,
COUNT( fruits_opt =  'Guava')AS Guava, 
COUNT( fruits_opt =  'Berry')AS Berry 
FROM beginner_1
GROUP BY DATETRUNC(date_ts,'dd')
ORDER BY DATETRUNC(date_ts,'dd');
```

Current result:

| day | no_of_fruits_sold | Guava | Berry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 120 | 120 | 120 |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 2021-01-09 00:00:00 | 80 | 80 | 80 |

Desired result:

| day | no_of_fruits_sold | Guava | Berry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 120 | 80 | 40 |
| 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 50 | 19 | 31 |
| 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 100 | 67 | 33 |
| 2021-01-09 00:00:00 | 80 | 52 | 28 |

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres? There is no `datetrunc()` function - only `date_trunc()`

Comment: I'm not using Postgres, but it has the closest syntax.

Comment: Then my answer is most probably useless now

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT(fruits_opt =  'Guava')` isn't doing what you think it does.

`fruits_opt =  'Guava'` returns `true` or `false` but never `null` so all rows are counted. And `count<expression>)` counts all rows where `<expression>` is not null

Use a filtered aggregation:

```
count(*) filter (where fruits_opt = 'Guava')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use count() on Boolean expression. use case to count 1 when your condition is true. If the condition is false then it will return null. Below query should serve your purpose:

```
SELECT 
DATETRUNC(date_ts,'dd') AS day,
COUNT(sold_fruits) AS no_of_fruits_sold,
COUNT( case when fruits_opt =  'Guava' then 1 end)AS Guava, 
COUNT( case when fruits_opt =  'Berry' then 1 end)AS Berry 
FROM beginner_1
GROUP BY DATETRUNC(date_ts,'dd')
ORDER BY DATETRUNC(date_ts,'dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what database you are using, so here is a compendium of options.

Standard SQL, but not supported in many databases:

```
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE fruits_opt =  'Guava') AS Guava,
```

Standard SQL, supported everywhere, but verbose:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN fruits_opt =  'Guava' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Guava
```

Standard SQL, supported everywhere, but verbose and I find the code a bit misleading because it returns the same values when `1` is replaced with `0` or `2` but not `NULL`:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN fruits_opt =  'Guava' THEN 1 END) as Guava
```

Non-standard, relies on implicit conversion to int:

```
SUM( fruits_opt =  'Guava' ) as Guava
```

Non-standard, uses Postgres shorthand for explicit conversion (and `::` is supported by many Postgres-derived databases):

```
SUM( (fruits_opt =  'Guava')::INT ) as Guava
```